# Auto fill date not include weekend

Tags: excel

I want to auto fill date in "A3" ("A3" is next day from "C2" and not is saturday and sunday)

[image]

Comment: autofill with the right mouse button and choose "fill weekdays"

Answer (score 0):

=WORKDAY(C2,1)

To add days excluding weekends, you can do as below:

Select a blank cell and type this formula =WORKDAY(C2,1), and press Enter key to get result.